# SWF Tools install/ setup of media players

Tags: 7

I'm trying to get any of the mp3 players in the SWF tools to work they all say *(under /admin/settings/swftools/handling)*:

**JW player:** *Missing flash_media_player/player-viral.swf*
**1 pixel out:** *Missing 1pixelout/player.swf*
*etc. for the other players...*

I followed the download link and tried putting the downloads under */SwfTools/Shared* -- and in the players direct folder e.x. */sites/all/libraries/mediaplayer4/player.swf*.  But, the missing file warning isn't going away which is preventing me from being able to activate any of the mp3 players.
I just wanna get these media players working.  Anyone come across this situation?  Thank you.

Comment: Problems related to a specific module should be placed in the module's issue queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  As you said chellman the version matter greatly.  I had to go under:
/admin/settings/swftools/flowplayer3 and under plugins I had to change the Player File from the default to flowplayer-3.0.7.swf.  Than you have to manually create the directory /sites/all/modules/swftools/shared/"flowplayer3" where you add the plugin.  So, there it is!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Drupal 6, since there's no stable release of swftools for D7 yet. The version of swftools you're using matters greatly here.  [Here's the documentation](http://drupal.org/node/303203).  The summary is that swftools 2 used the swftools module folder (which is usually in sites/all/modules), while swftools 3 uses sites/all/libraries.